# How to differentiate between @click and @keyup.enter in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseevent, keyevent

I have the following button:

```
<button @click="toggleModal" @keydown.enter="toggleModalWithFocusTrap">
```

It seems to me that in vue both events `click` and `enter` are equivalent. This leads me to the problem that both events `toggleModal` and `toggleModalWithFocusTrap` are called at the same time,  which immediately closes the modal since `this.showModal = !this.showModal` is set to `true` first, and set to `false` immediately afterward.

Thus my **question** is how to determine if the event is triggered by a mouse click or pressing enter on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler add the parameter that represents the event, then get the event name from the `type` attribute :

```
toggleModal(event){

   if(event.type==='click'){
       // do some stuff

   }else if(event.type==='keydown'){
        // do other stuff
   }


}
```